# calculating rate of accpetance based on action in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm practicing queries, this was one of the ask

> What is the overall friend acceptance rate by date? Your output should have the rate of acceptances by the date the request was sent. Order by the earliest date to latest.

Assume that each friend request starts by a user sending ("*user_id_sender*") a friend request to another user ("*user_id_receiver*"), who is logged in the table with `action = 'sent'`. If the request is accepted, the table logs `action = 'accepted'`. If the request is not accepted, no records are added.

Sample input table:

| user_id_sender | user_id_receiver | date | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ad4943sdz | 948ksx123d | 2020-01-04 | sent |
| ad4943sdz | 948ksx123d | 2020-01-06 | accepted |
| dfdfxf9483 | 9djjjd9283 | 2020-01-04 | sent |

Tried with the following query.

```
SELECT date,
       COUNT(*) AS total_requests,
       SUM(action) AS total_accepted,
       ROUND(SUM(action) / COUNT(*), 2) AS acceptance_rate
FROM fb_friend_requests
WHERE action="accepted"
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY date
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: What is your expected output? And why your query doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You cannot sum a string field.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.date,
    count(b.date) / count(a.date) as percentage_acceptance
from (
    select user_id_sender, date
    from fb_friend_requests
    where action = 'sent'
    ) as a
left join (
    select user_id_sender, date
    from fb_friend_requests
    where action = 'accepted'
    ) as b
using (user_id_sender)
group by date
```